# Is there a way to mark template driven form as initialy "touched" without setTimeout?

Tags: angular

So lets have input

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" name="myname" required [(ngModel)]="comment">
    <mat-error>Is required lol</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and I want it to be invalid on init so I "touch" it

```
export class InputOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  comment = null;
  @ViewChild('f')
  form: NgForm


  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.form.controls);
    console.log(typeof this.form.controls);
    console.log(Object.keys(this.form.controls));

    console.log(this.form.controls.myname);
    console.log(this.form.controls['myname']);
    this.form.controls.myname.markAsTouched();
    })
  }
```

Is there a way to do it without setting timeout? For now, it is delayed in order to let form to initialize itself. **Using `AfterViewInit` init hook does not help**.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urqles-rbmto8

Comment: @Downvoter - its quite clear what I am about to achieve here - remove `setTimeout` from `onInit`. How to improve for you to be much clearer ?

Comment: Does putting it in [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) help?

Comment: @TamásSzabó tested and no

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your demo, it appears that you want to show the "required" error state before users touch it.

If that's the case, you can implement a custom ErrorStateMatcher.

```
class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control, form) {
    return !!(control && control.invalid);
  }
}
```

With MyErrorStateMatcher, isErrorState would return true whenever the input is invalid, even before the user touches it.

(The default ErrorStateMatcher is something like below:

```
export class ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.touched || (form && form.submitted)));
  }
}
```

with default error state matcher, isErrorState won't return true before the field is touched by the user)

Answer (score -1):

You can try `AfterViewInit` with little twist as shown below:

```
export class InputOverviewExample implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
comment = null;
@ViewChild('f') protected f;
form: NgForm


ngOnInit() {
}

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.f);
    this.f.touched= true;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urqles-rbmto8)

Comment: I think you have not forked the example. Moreover this will not work.